# Deriving kinematics equations for constant jerk

Tags: physics, calculus, kinematics

I am trying to find the constant jerk analog to the extremely useful constant acceleration equation

```
a=v^2/2s 
or 
v^2-v1^2=2a(s-s1)
```

It has no term for time, which is useful if you are looking for other parameters.

So far I have derived the simple equations for the changes in acceleration, velocity, and displacement:

```
a1=a+jt
a1^2-a^2=2j(v-v1)
v1=v+1/2(a+a1)t
v1=v+at+1/2jt^2
s1=s+vt+1/2at^2+1/6jt^3
```

Any help to provide the equation to find the constant jerk equation without time is greatly appreciated. Cheers!